# OpenFileDialog unhandled exception

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I am working in VS2013 using the `OpenFileDialog` from a module and it works great once. If the user opens it again this error is displayed:

> "ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Positive length is expected"

My code:

```
Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
Try
    With fd
        .Title = "Select File Dialog"
        .InitialDirectory = str_PathFileName
        .FileName = Path.GetFileName(str_PathFileName)
        .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .Multiselect = False
        .RestoreDirectory = True
        If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        ...
```

The error happens on the `ShowDialog` line. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `str_PathFileName` when it crashes?  There also might be more information in the Details of the exception dialog

Comment: do a dispose of openfiledialog after showdialog returns

Comment: adding fd.Dispose() had no effect

Comment: str_PathFileName on a second use contains a valid path and filename.

Comment: If I comment out all of the OpenFileDialog parameters except ShowDialog, I still get the error:

Comment: `If I comment out all of the OpenFileDialog parameters except ShowDialog, I still get the error` I think you are not providing all of the code...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name str_PathFileName might be empty. Check is your path good.

```
           Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            Dim str_PathFileName As String = "C:\"  'put your valid path

            With fd
                    .Title = "Select File Dialog"
                    .InitialDirectory = str_PathFileName
                    .FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(str_PathFileName)
                    .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
                    .Multiselect = False
                    .RestoreDirectory = True
                    If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

                    End If

                End With
```

This should pass

Comment: `Your variable name str_PathFileName might be empty` this should have been a comment, not an answer as the code you posted was the same and didn't address any differences.Therefore the code isn't relative at all at this point.

Comment: @Terabithia Perhaps your path is deleted for the second time when opens. Use debug to check path at second attempt.

Comment: I have confirmed the path on the second use is valid, and by default is the same as on the first use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me in a simple Sub() with just your code in it - try moving your code to a button click event and see if it stall fails.

Here is a variation that may clean things up a bit better:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim str_PathFileName As String = "C:\Temp"  'put your valid path
    Using fd As New OpenFileDialog
        With fd
            .Title = "Select File Dialog"
            .InitialDirectory = str_PathFileName
            .FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(str_PathFileName)
            .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
            .Multiselect = False
            .RestoreDirectory = True
            Dim result As DialogResult = .ShowDialog
            MsgBox(result.ToString)
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this application there is no button to use, the OpenFileDialog is launched by the application, not the user.

Comment: I was proposing the Button_Click as a way to isolate the code to see if something else in your program is interfering. Are you build a Console app? WinForm, WPF? ??